# next() multiple times in .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm looking for a way to call next() multiple times until I get to the specific row in a .csv file (basically skipping everything until the row I want) eg.

```
import csv

file = 'weatherfileexample.csv'

with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headings = next(f) # I want this to be row 12 where Year;Month;Day;Hour;Minute;.... is located
```

Contents of .csv file looks like this.

```
LAT;;;;;47.0458;47.0458;47.0458;47.0458;47.0458;47.0458;47.0458
LON;;;;;21.9183;21.9183;21.9183;21.9183;21.9183;21.9183;21.9183
ASL;;;;;126.000;126.000;126.000;126.000;126.000;126.000;126.000
CITY;;;;;Oradea;Oradea;Oradea;Oradea;Oradea;Oradea;Oradea
DOMAIN;;;;;NEMS4;NEMS4;NEMS4;NEMS4;NEMS4;NEMS4;NEMS4
LEVEL;;;;;2 m above gnd;10 m above gnd;10 m above gnd;2 m above gnd;2 m above gnd;10 m above gnd;10 m above gnd
NAME;;;;;Temperature;Wind Speed;Wind Direction;Temperature;Temperature;Wind Speed;Wind Speed
UNIT;;;;;°C;km/h;°;°C;°C;km/h;km/h
AGGREGATION;;;;;daily mean;daily mean;daily mean;daily max;daily min;daily max;daily min
UTC_OFFSET;;;;;2;2;2;2;2;2;2

Year;Month;Day;Hour;Minute;Temperature daily mean [2 m above gnd];Wind Speed daily mean [10 m above gnd];Wind Direction daily mean [10 m above gnd];Temperature daily max [2 m above gnd];Temperature daily min [2 m above gnd];Wind Speed daily max [10 m above gnd];Wind Speed daily min [10 m above gnd]
2019;12;14;00;00;6.74;13.75;170.60;11.32;3.43;21.14;2.60
2019;12;15;00;00;5.60;18.08;186.24;10.92;1.31;26.05;11.17
```

Basically I want my :

headings = highllighted text in .csv and continue from there.

I know I can easily edit the .csv file but I want to know how to do it.

Things I tried

heading = next(f) * 12 # 12 is where the data that I need is , this just multiplied the firstrow 12 times

also tried:

heading = next(f, 12) # This just game me the first row.

Thank you very much!

P.S. : Pastebin had issues loading so I couldn't paste .csv there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[next(f) for i in range(12)]
headings = next(f)
```

Or

```
data = list(f)
headings = data[12]
```

Comment: The second option reads the entire file into memory, and accesses the wrong variable. I guess you mean `data[12]`.

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) will skip elements in an iterable while a given condition is satisfied.  Combining this with the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function enables processing rows only once a particular row has been reached.

In this code the condition for dropping a row is that the line number returned by `enumerate` is less than 11 (`enumerate` uses zero-based counting by default).

```
>>> import csv, itertools
>>> with open('weatherfileexample.csv', newline='') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
...     # dropwhile returns the index from enumerate, which we can ignore, and
...     # the row from csv.reader.
...     for _, row in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x :x[0] < 11, enumerate(reader)):
...         print(row)
... 
['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Temperature daily mean [2 m above gnd]', 'Wind Speed daily mean [10 m above gnd]', 'Wind Direction daily mean [10 m above gnd]', 'Temperature daily max [2 m above gnd]', 'Temperature daily min [2 m above gnd]', 'Wind Speed daily max [10 m above gnd]', 'Wind Speed daily min [10 m above gnd]']
['2019', '12', '14', '00', '00', '6.74', '13.75', '170.60', '11.32', '3.43', '21.14', '2.60']
['2019', '12', '15', '00', '00', '5.60', '18.08', '186.24', '10.92', '1.31', '26.05', '11.17']
```

Using `dropwhile` is excessive for trivial cases, but potentially useful if the condition is complex and / or performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `readlines()` :

```py
with open(file) as f:
    line = f.readlines()
line[12]
```

```
'2019;12;14;00;00;6.74;13.75;170.60;11.32;3.43;21.14;2.60\n'
```

Comment: This has the flaw that it needlessly reads the entire file into memory. Reading a line at a time scales even to humongous files, and lets you stop and quit as soon as you get to the line you need, which is obvisuosly more efficient, too.